# Issue with Magento sidebar content block position

Tags: xml, magento-1.9

I am completely new to Magento and XML (I am using 1.9 CE), I have read through a lot to get to this point and I am having trouble with a magento left sidebar category block which is the side nav of the page. I have been asked to move the custom left sidebar block I created above it. The nav block is a predefined Magento block SO, I tried this snippet of code in the local.xml file of my theme default directory:

```
    <reference name="left">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>umm.sidemenu</name></action>
    <action method="insert">
    <blockName>umm.sidemenu</blockName>
    <siblingName>block_left_top</siblingName>
    <after>1</after>
    </action>
    </reference>
```

An article I read suggested trying to unset the child block and insert it again using the code above. It works however I now get an instance of the categories above AND below my sibling custom content block. Is there something I can do to remove the top instance? Or did I miss something along the way? Some guidance on this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: I got the same result by removing the XML above and replacing it with the following XML

<block type="ultramegamenu/navigation" name="umm.sidemenu" template="infortis/ultramegamenu/categories.phtml" after="block_left_top" />

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to declare the sibling name in the menu's XML file which was declared as another block. I wrote the right code on local.xml but it already existed somewhere else and I ended up with a duplicate. THANKS ANYWAYS!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to declare the sibling name in the menu's XML file which was declared as another block. I wrote the right code on local.xml but it already existed somewhere else and I ended up with a duplicate. THANKS ANYWAYS!